# active record query returns hash of user_ids, find user attributes for each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find

User has many Relationships

In my relationships table i have a field :referee containing a user_id for each record.
Each record also has user_id foreign key

I want to find the records that have current_user.id in the :referee field and select user_id from the foreign key field for each one.

```
refs = Relationship.where(:referee => current_user.id).select("user_id").all
```

This results in an array like this,

```
[#<Relationship user_id: 16>, #<Relationship user_id: 17>]
```

I now want to find User attributes for each of the ids in the array, I've tried but so far failed, for example:

```
User.where(:id => @refs_user_id).each do |user|
  user.name
end
```

Did some reading/watching on active record advanced queries, scopes etc but can't quite seem to grasp what's required here. Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select just the `user_id` components like this:

```
User.where(:id => @refs_user_id.map(&:user_id)).each do |user|
  user.name
end
```

Comment: thanks for that, getting a nil object error occurred while evaluating nil.map though?

Comment: I assumed `@refs_user_id` was holding the results of your `Relationship.where(...)` query. If it's really `refs`, then use `refs.map(&:user_id)`

Comment: Thanks Dylan, my understanding of active record querying is pretty basic. Is this the proper way to go about a query like this?

Comment: `User.find(@refs_user_id.map(&:user_id))` is little shorter ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass an array of ids to `ActiveRecord`

```
 User.find([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

And if you just want to get the ids:

```
     User.find(:all, :conditions => 'id IN (?)',[1,2,3,4,5,6], :select => 'id')
```

That will only return the ids.

Comment: Thanks @codeglot, the array returned in my query seems to the problem so - how can i return an array containing only the id numbers?